# add circle in the center of marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to add a circle in the map,in the location of the current marker that i get from google maps is that possible?My knowledge in the html &javascript is very limit.
here is the code i have ..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reverse Geocoding</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }

    </style>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>


 var geocoder;
 var map;
 var marker;
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


 function initializeMap() {

     if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
             revereGeoCode(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
         });
     } else {
         console.log("er")
         // make sure to handle the failure
     }

     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 20,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.078111, 23.734414),
         mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
     }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
 }

 function revereGeoCode(lat, lng) {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     geocoder.geocode({
         'LatLng': LatLng
     }, function (results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             if (results[1]) {
              // place your marker coding
                map.setZoom(20);

                // Define circle options
                var circleOptions = {
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.35,
                    map: map,
                    center: latlng,
                    radius: 20
                };

                // Add the circle to the map.
                var markerCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map

                });



                 infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                 infowindow.open(map, marker);
             } else {
                 alert('No results found');
             }
         } else {
             alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
         }


     });
 }




 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
   </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the html &javascript is very limit. here is the code i have ..

Comment: Did you read the documentation, what kind of problems do you have with adding a circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create the circle and define its center using the same coordinates than your marker.

```
// Define circle options
var circleOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: latlng,
    radius: 20
};

// Add the circle to the map.
var markerCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
```

That's it.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/vm5qj5jk/)</kbd>

Comment: i have updated my code and the console is clear with no errors,but i don't get the marker,infowindow or the circle in the map :(

Comment: yes i have see it and working on this,the problem is no marker show up when i give the lat,long **center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.078111, 23.734414)** the screen is on center..

Comment: Are you not able to compare a few lines of code? Why did you change some properties to wrong stuff? When you have a **working example** then you better use it (copy the code and use it). And use your javascript console to debug. The error is pretty obvious!

Comment: **Uncaught ReferenceError: LatLng is not defined** and **Uncaught InvalidValueError: unknown property LatLng**. Just compare this line `'LatLng': LatLng` with my code...

Answer (score 1):

```
    function initializeMap() {

     if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
             revereGeoCode(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
         });
     } else {
         console.log("er")
         // make sure to handle the failure
     }

     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 18,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885, -73.997383),
         mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
     }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
 }

 function revereGeoCode(lat, lng) {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     geocoder.geocode({
         'latLng': latlng
     }, function (results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             if (results[0]) {
                 // place your marker coding
                 map.setZoom(20);
                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: latlng,
                     map: map
                     **/* You Should to add this*/**
                     icon: iconBase + 'circle.png'

  });
                 infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                 infowindow.open(map, marker);
             } else {
                 alert('No results found');
             }
         } else {
             alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
         }


     });
 }
```